# Properly use 'this' in jquery

Tags: jquery, class, this

I have created this iOS-like menu and I'm trying to make the slide right work when you click on a certain category. I have made something that works [here](https://codepen.io/wydmae/pen/owdZzM) but with only one div that needs clicking (showing `.page.second`).

Now when I try to do the same on [this](https://codepen.io/wydmae/pen/zzjqoe?editors=1000) longer menu, it needs more editing because there are several clickable `<h1>` that can lead to different `.page.second`. I wanted to know if I could succeed thanks to a 'this' or if the only option was to name all the pages and refer to them one by one in the jquery code?

I'm not sure this is very clear, please ask questions if you didn't understand something, or what I wanted to do!

Thanks for the help!

```js
$('.mtitle').click(function(){
  $('.page.second').show()
});
$('.back').click(function(){
  $('.page.second').hide()
})
```

```css
#main{
  position:relative;
  width:600px;
  height:700px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  border:2px solid #aaa;
  border-radius:10px;
}
.space{
  height:35px;
  margin:0;
  border-bottom:1px solid #aaa;
}
.page{
  top:0;
  left:0;
  background:#ddd;
  -webkit-transition: 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: 1s ease;
  -o-transition: 1s ease;
  transition: 1s ease;
}
.page p{
  text-align:center;
  font-size:25px;
  font-family:Helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight:700;
}
.top{
  border-bottom:1px solid #333;
  background:#fff;
  margin-bottom:20px;
}
.page.second{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
.back{
  cursor:pointer;
  border:none;
  color:#0084ff;
  font-family:helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
  background:transparent;
}
.mtitle{
  background:#fff;
  cursor:pointer;
  width:100%;
  display:inline-block;
}

.mtitle img{
  float:left;
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  margin:8px 10px;
}
.mtitle h1{
  color:#222;
  border-bottom:1px solid #aaa;
  margin:0;
  padding:10px;
  font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:500;
}
.mtitle i{
  float:right;
  color:#aaa;
  margin-right:5px;
  font-size:20px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px white;
  line-height:40px;
}

.tags{
  width:100%;
  float:right;
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
}
.tags a, .droptitle{
  display:inline-block;
  text-decoration:none;
  width:100%;
  color:#222;
  background:#fff;
  border-bottom:1px solid #aaa;
  margin:0;
  padding:10px;
  line-height:25px;
  font-family:Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size:18px;
  font-weight:500;  
}
.droptitle i{  float:right;
  color:#aaa;
  margin-right:5px;
  font-size:20px;
  -webkit-text-stroke: 2px white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/randomcolor/0.5.2/randomColor.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/3ikgvxs/0TGl4zgpu/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.collapse.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="jquery.style-my-tooltips.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/imovwvl/dJWl20ley/jqueryformasonry.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://static.tumblr.com/rzl30kg/eAxm7a751/jquery.style-my-tooltips.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">



<!--- custom font --->
<p>{Title} - All links</p>


<div id="main">

<!--- MAIN LINKS --->
<div class="page">
  <div class="top">
  <p>General</p>
  </div>
  
  <div class="mtitle">

<img src="https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/iOS/ios10-home-app-icon.png"/>
<h1>Home</h1>
  </div>
  
<div class="mtitle">

<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/wineass/ios7-redesign/512/Messages-icon.png"/>
<h1>Contact</h1>
  </div>

  
<div class="mtitle">

<img src="http://www.iphonefaq.org/files/styles/large/public/apple-music-icon.png?itok=QhxPjcJq"/>
<h1>Soundtrack</h1>
  </div>
  
<div class="mtitle">

<img src="https://frenchmac-frenchmac1.netdna-ssl.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/iOS7_photos_multiply.png"/>
<h1>Icons</h1>
  </div>
  <div class="space"></div>
<!--- box one start --->

<div class="mtitle">

<img src="https://conceptdraw.com/a2623c3/p8/preview/640/pict--videos-app-icons---vector-stencils-library.png--diagram-flowchart-example.png"/>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
<h1>TV Shows</h1>
  </div>

</div><!--End page 1-->
  

<div class="page second">
  <div class="top">
  <button class="back"><i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> General</button>
  <p>TV Shows</p>
  </div>
  
<div class="tags" hidden>

<div class="droptitle">brooklyn nine-nine<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></div>

    <div class="droptags">
<a href="/tagged/amy_santiago">Amy Santiago</a>
<a href="/tagged/charles_boyle">Charles Boyle</a>
<a href="/tagged/gina_linetti">Gina Linetti</a>
<a href="/tagged/hitchcock">Hitchcock</a>
<a href="/tagged/jake_peralta">Jake Peralta</a>
<a href="/tagged/raymond_holt">Raymond Holt</a>
<a href="/tagged/rosa_diaz">Rosa Diaz</a>
<a href="/tagged/scully">Scully</a>
<a href="/tagged/terry_jeffords">Terry Jeffords</a>
    </div>

<div class="droptitle">friends <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></div>

    <div class="droptags">
<a href="/tagged/Rachel Green">Rachel Green</a>
<a href="/tagged/Monica Geller">Monica Geller</a>
<a href="/tagged/Phoebe Buffay">Phoebe Buffay</a>
<a href="/tagged/Joey Tribbiani">Joey Tribbiani</a>
<a href="/tagged/Chandler Bing">Chandler Bing</a>
<a href="/tagged/Ross Geller">Ross Geller</a>
    </div>
    
<a href="/tagged/game of thrones">game of thrones</a>
<a href="/tagged/himym">how i met your mother</a>
<a href="/tagged/htgawm">how to get away with murder</a>
<a href="/tagged/jane the virgin">jane the virgin</a>
<a href="/tagged/new girl">new girl</a>
<a href="/tagged/one tree hill">one tree hill</a>
<a href="/tagged/oitnb">orange is the new black</a>

<div class="droptitle">orphan black <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></div>

    <div class="droptags">
<a href="/tagged/alison_hendrix">Alison Hendrix</a>
<a href="/tagged/beth_childs">Beth Childs</a>
<a href="/tagged/cosima_niehaus">Cosima Niehaus</a>
<a href="/tagged/delphine_cormier">Delphine Cormier</a>
<a href="/tagged/donnie_hendrix">Donnie Hendrix</a>
<a href="/tagged/felix_dawkins">Felix Dawkins</a>
<a href="/tagged/helena">Helena</a>
<a href="/tagged/kira_manning">Kira Manning</a>
<a href="/tagged/krystal_goderitch">Krystal Goderitch</a>
<a href="/tagged/paul_dierden">Paul Dierden</a>
<a href="/tagged/rachel_duncan">Rachel Duncan</a>
<a href="/tagged/sarah_manning">Sarah Manning</a>
<a href="/tagged/siobhan_sadler">Siobhan Sadler</a>
    </div>
    
<div class="droptitle">skam <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></div>

<div class="droptags">
    <div class="droptitle">main characters <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></div>
        <div class="droptags">
<a href="/tagged/Eva Kviig Mohn">Eva Kviig Mohn</a>
<a href="/tagged/Noora Amalie S&aelig;tre">Noora Amalie S&aelig;tre</a>
<a href="/tagged/Isak Valtersen">Isak Valtersen</a>
<a href="/tagged/Sana Bakkoush">Sana Bakkoush</a>
        </div>
<a href="/tagged/Chris_Berg">Chris Berg</a>
<a href="/tagged/Christoffer_Schistad">Christoffer Schistad</a>
<a href="/tagged/Eskild_Tryggvason">Eskild Tryggvason</a>
<a href="/tagged/Even_Bech_N&aelig;sheim">Even Bech N&aelig;sheim</a>
<a href="/tagged/Ingrid_Theis_Gaupseth">Ingrid Theis Gaupseth</a>
<a href="/tagged/Jonas_Noah_Vasquez">Jonas Noah Vasquez</a>
<a href="/tagged/Linn_Larsen_Hansen">Linn Larsen Hansen</a>
<a href="/tagged/Magnus_Fossbakken">Magnus Fossbakken</a>
<a href="/tagged/Mahdi_Disi">Mahdi Disi</a>
<a href="/tagged/Sara_N&oslash;rrstelien">Sara N&oslash;rrstelien</a>
<a href="/tagged/Vilde_Lien_Hellerud">Vilde Lien Hellerud</a>
<a href="/tagged/William_Magnusson">William Magnusson</a>
    </div>

<div class="droptitle">once upon a time <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></div>

    <div class="droptags">
<a href="/tagged/August_Booth">August Booth</a>
<a href="/tagged/Belle_French">Belle French</a>
<a href="/tagged/David_Nolan">David Nolan</a>
<a href="/tagged/Emma Swan">Emma Swan</a>
<a href="/tagged/siobhan_sadler">Graham Humbert</a>
<a href="/tagged/Henry_Mills">Henry Daniel Mills</a>
<a href="/tagged/Jefferson">Jefferson</a>
<a href="/tagged/Killian_Jones">Killian Jones</a>
<a href="/tagged/Mary_Margaret_Blanchard">Mary Margaret Blanchard</a>
<a href="/tagged/Neal_Cassidy">Neal Cassidy</a>
<a href="/tagged/Regina_Mills">Regina Mills</a>
<a href="/tagged/Robin_Hood">Robin Hood</a>
<a href="/tagged/Ruby">Ruby</a>
<a href="/tagged/felix_dawkins">Rumplestiltskin</a>
<a href="/tagged/Zelena">Zelena</a>
    </div>
    
<a href="/tagged/stranger things">stranger things</a>
<a href="/tagged/13 reasons why">13 reasons why</a></div>

<!--- one end --->
  
  </div><!-- End page TV Shows -->



<!--- two start --->
<div class="mtitle">
  
<img src="http://cdn.osxdaily.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/06/health-app-icon.png"/>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
<h1>Ships</h1>
  </div>

  <div class="page second">
<div class="tags" hidden>
<a href="/tagged/emma x regina">Emma &amp; Regina</a>
<a href="/tagged/noora x william">Noora &amp; William</a>
<a href="/tagged/frank x laurel">Frank &amp; Laurel</a>
<a href="/tagged/magnus x vilde">Magnus &amp; Vilde</a>
</div>
    </div>

<!--- two end --->



<!--- three start --->
<div class="mtitle">

<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iynque/ios7-style/1024/Contacts-icon.png"/>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
<h1>Actors</h1>
  </div>

    <div class="tags" hidden>
<a href="/tagged/Alfie Enoch">Alfie Enoch</a>
<a href="/tagged/Andy Samberg">Andy Samberg</a>
<a href="/tagged/Bruno Mars">Bruno Mars</a>
<a href="/tagged/Charlie Heaton">Charlie Heaton</a>
<a href="/tagged/Chloe Bennet">Chloe Bennet</a>
<a href="/tagged/Chris Hemsworth">Chris Hemsworth</a>
<a href="/tagged/Chris Pratt">Chris Pratt</a>
<a href="/tagged/Cobie Smulders">Cobie Smulders</a>
<a href="/tagged/Daniel Sharman">Daniel Sharman</a>
<a href="/tagged/Danielle Panabaker">Danielle Panabaker</a>
<a href="/tagged/Dylan Minnette">Dylan Minnette</a>
<a href="/tagged/Emilia Clarke">Emilia Clarke</a>
<a href="/tagged/Evelyne Brochu">Evelyne Brochu</a>
<a href="/tagged/Gina Rodriguez">Gina Rodriguez</a>
<a href="/tagged/Halsey">Halsey</a>
<a href="/tagged/Jack Falahee">Jack Falahee</a>
<a href="/tagged/Jamie Dornan">Jamie Dornan</a>
<a href="/tagged/Jennifer Aniston">Jennifer Aniston</a>
<a href="/tagged/Jennifer Morrison">Jennifer Morrison</a>
<a href="/tagged/Jessica Alba">Jessica Alba</a>
<a href="/tagged/Justin Baldoni">Justin Baldoni</a>
<a href="/tagged/Karla Souza">Karla Souza</a>
<a href="/tagged/Kate Mara">Kate Mara</a>
<a href="/tagged/Katherine Langford">Katherine Langford</a>
<a href="/tagged/Katherine McNamara">Katherine McNamara</a>
<a href="/tagged/Katie Cassidy">Katie Cassidy</a>
<a href="/tagged/Kit Harington">Kit Harington</a>
<a href="/tagged/Lana Parrilla">Lana Parrilla</a>
<a href="/tagged/Leighton Messter">Leighton Meester</a>
<a href="/tagged/Lily Collins">Lily Collins</a>
<a href="/tagged/Lisa Kudrow">Lisa Kudrow</a>
<a href="/tagged/Madelaine Petsch">Madelaine Petsch</a>
<a href="/tagged/Margot Robbie">Margot Robbie</a>
<a href="/tagged/Max Greenfield">Max Greenfield</a>
<a href="/tagged/Melissa Fumero">Melissa Fumero</a>
<a href="/tagged/Natalie Dormer">Natalie Dormer</a>
<a href="/tagged/Natalia Dyer">Natalia Dyer</a>
<a href="/tagged/Richard Madden">Richard Madden</a>
<a href="/tagged/Rose Leslie">Rose Leslie</a>
<a href="/tagged/Rose McIver">Rose McIver</a>
<a href="/tagged/Sarah Paulson">Sarah Paulson</a>
<a href="/tagged/Selena Gomez">Selena Gomez</a>
<a href="/tagged/Stephanie Beatriz">Stephanie Beatriz</a>
<a href="/tagged/Stephen Amell">Stephen Amell</a>
<a href="/tagged/Sophia Bush">Sophia Bush</a>
<a href="/tagged/Sophie Turner">Sophie Turner</a>
<a href="/tagged/Tatiana Maslany">Tatiana Maslany</a>
<a href="/tagged/Theo James">Theo James</a>
<a href="/tagged/Theresa Eggesb&oslash;">Theresa Eggesb&oslash;</a>
<a href="/tagged/Yael Grobglas">Yael Grobglas</a>
<a href="/tagged/Zooey Deschanel">Zooey Deschanel</a>
    </div>

<!--- three end --->



<!--- four start --->
<div class="mtitle">

<img src="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/iynque/ios7-style/1024/Notes-icon.png"/>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
<h1>Post types</h1>
  </div>

    <div class="tags" hidden>
<a href="/tagged/gifset">gif</a>
<a href="/tagged/photoset">photo</a>
<a href="/tagged/icons">icons</a>
<a href="/tagged/tutorial">tutorial</a>
<a href="/tagged/answered">answer</a>
<a href="/tagged/edits">edit</a>
    </div>

<!--- four end --->


<!--- five start --->
<div class="mtitle">
  
<img src="https://conceptdraw.com/a2623c3/p8/preview/640/pict--videos-app-icons---vector-stencils-library.png--diagram-flowchart-example.png"/>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
<h1>Movies</h1>
  </div>

    <div class="tags" hidden>
<a href="/tagged/Guardians of the Galaxy">Guardians of the Galaxy</a>
<a href="/tagged/The End of the Longing">The End of the Longing</a>
<a href="/tagged/Suicide Squad">Suicide Squad</a>
<a href="/tagged/La La Land">La La Land</a>
    </div>
<!--- five end --->


<!--- six start --->
<div class="mtitle">

<img src="https://support.apple.com/library/content/dam/edam/applecare/images/en_US/iphone/iphone6/books-app-icon.png"/>
<i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
<h1>Magazines</h1>
  
  </div>

    <div class="tags" hidden>
<a href="/tagged/complex magazine">Complex</a>
<a href="/tagged/evening standard magazine">Evening Standard</a>
<a href="/tagged/daman magazine">Daman</a>
<a href="/tagged/darling magazine">Darling</a>
<a href="/tagged/la times magazine">LA Times</a>
<a href="/tagged/nkd magazine">NKD</a>
<a href="/tagged/popular tv magazine">Popular TV</a>
<a href="/tagged/shape magazine">Shape</a>
<a href="/tagged/vanity fair magazine">Vanity Fair</a>
<a href="/tagged/vogue magazine">Vogue</a>
<a href="/tagged/wwd magazine">WWD</a>
    </div>
```

Comment: I really did int get you want exactly you want to do?

Comment: Have you tried either of the two methods that you mentioned?

Comment: I'm not sure how to use this and that's why I asked here. I have tried the other method but it makes a huge amount of jquery code.. @hRdCoder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try adding a 'data' attribute to each link and check the value each time it is clicked. I created a very minified version of what you have in jsFiddle as sort of a proof-of-concept.

```
$('p.link').click(function(evt) {
    $('#home').hide();
    switch ($(this).attr('data')) {
    case 'page1': $('#page1').show(); break;
    case 'page2': $('#page2').show(); break;
    case 'page3': $('#page3').show(); break;
    case 'page4': $('#page4').show(); break;
    case 'page5': $('#page5').show(); break;
  };
});
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m942yamw/)

Comment: Thank you for your answer!! I actually applied it to my theme and it worked although now there's a little problem it's that the other '.page.second' when going back to home are displaying, I'm not sure why

Comment: Great to hear that it's working better for you. I noticed you have a $('.page').show() in your javascript. That's going to show every "<div class="page " when you click the back button. You might have to change it to show just the last page that you came from. This might explain why you are seeing the other ".page.second' as you mentioned.

Comment: You could write your own .last() function that would work for your app. In the HTML, one thing you can try is using nested elements to keep the content organized by each page and a good naming convention so you can access each page with jQuery so you can easily do what you need to. If you're not sure about how to do it, keep fiddling with codepen or jsFiddle and you will get it eventually. :)

Comment: Ok thank you! Do you mind me asking something else? Maybe in chat?

Comment: I know there's a stackoverflow chat but I don't know how to invite you in a new room..^^' Do you have another way maybe?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148340/discussion-between-hrdcoder-and-maelle-jumel).

Comment: That's just not the way to code in JS. Instead of hardcoding cases - JS code should be flexible, instead of using `case` you should let JS independent from what you're doing in HTML and still make it work.

Comment: Hey I left you a message on the chat! :)

Answer (score 1):

If your `.page`*s* are tightly coupled with some trigger buttons the best way is to use `data-*` attribute like:

```
<div class="mtitle" data-toggle="Some page">Some page</div>
```

and as you can already see, it's used to couple it with this page:

```
<div class="page" data-togglable="Some page">Some page content</div>
```

using the matching data value of `"Some page"`.

---

Here's a quick example as a minified proof of concept

```js
(function() {

  var $togglable = $("[data-togglable]"), // Collect all pages
      $target; // Used to store the last opened target page


  $("[data-toggle]").on("click", function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();  // prevent default browser behavior
    e.stopPropagation(); // prevent button click propagate to a parent button
    
    var dataID = $(this).data("toggle"); // Get the data value "ID" (i.e: "Page 1")

    $target = $("[data-togglable='" + dataID + "']");
    
    $togglable.not( $target ).stop().slideUp(); // Slide all up (not the target page)
    $target.stop().slideToggle();               // Toggle the target page

  });

}());
```

```css
.mtitle{border:1px solid #eee;}
.page{display:none; background: #eee;}
```

```html
<div class="mtitle" data-toggle="Page 1">Page 1</div>
<div class="page" data-togglable="Page 1">
  Some page 1 content
</div>

<div class="mtitle" data-toggle="Page 2">Page 2</div>
<div class="page" data-togglable="Page 2">
  Some page 2 content
</div>

<a data-toggle="Page 2">I also toggle page 2</a>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for answering, so to be sure, I should just add the js and 'data-toggle="whatever" ' and 'data-togglable="whatever" ' to the wanted pages? Or is there something else I need to do? Also the thing is if all but the targeted page slides up, we won't be able to return back to the first page?

Comment: I've updated what I think you meant on the codepen, and I probably understood something wrong because I can't make it work. Here's the codepen : https://codepen.io/wydmae/pen/zzjqoe?editors=1010

Comment: @MaëlleJumel 1. yes. 2. that's all. 3. It's just a proof of concept. You don't need to use  `.slideUp()` and `.slideToggle()`, you can use `hide()` and `.toggle()` or `.removeClass()` and `.toggleClass()` - it all depends.  Go trough all the code and comment it the way you understand it - until you really start to make sense out of it.

Comment: @MaëlleJumel also what's the `function iosFunction(){` doign there?

Comment: Ok thank you I will do that! I'll let you know when it works. (I changed the iosFunction, it was just something I tried sorry ^^

Comment: @MaëlleJumel sorry for not using your exact code and making it hard for you :( but I'm not sure to understand your exact expected hide / show thing - instead what I'm proposing is just a concept. If - the way it works in my example fits your requirements, all  you need to do is to port the essential parts into your structure. If you cannot make it let me know and I'll figure out something using your example (although I find really hard to go trough your 500 lines of code and do edits. You sould also always try to provide a [mcve])

Comment: Hey no worries! I know it's annoying to try and make it work with a long code like that. I think I understood the way your code works but I can't seem to make it work with mine :/ too bad

Comment: @MaëlleJumel too bad, yes, as I've said all you have to do is use `.hide()` `.show()` or whatever you specifically need - the answer you picked as correct - might work currently for your specific case but it's just plain wrong and not the way to code. You should **never** run and modify a JS file by only adding an extra page into your HTML.

Comment: I did try with .show() and .hide(). It was for sure my bad for not being able to make it work, maybe I had something else wrong? the data-togglable but I really tried to match everything. But I couldn't make it work, so I used the other solution, working. Sorry